# Importing .csv file leads to col_double col_type

Tags: r, csv

I am having problems reading a CSV file that has a column (Value) with numbers only (integer, positive and negative).

`read_csv` imports this column as col_double and I can not convert it to integer or numeric.

I tried:

```
df <- read_csv("C:/STAN00a10.csv"))
```

Using option col_type do not work.

I also tried importing from excel file with the same result:

```
df <- read_xlsx("C:/STAN00a10.xlsx"))
```

Converting after importing do not work:

```
df$Value<-as.numeric(df$Value)
```

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7G8gKdl3TowbHJmNWJDWkZnR3M/view?usp=sharing
Note that this file is 94 MB large!

Comment: `col_double` means it was parsed as double, which is numeric. You can verify that by `is.numeric(df$Value)`.

Comment: So it's really not a problem. Just a lack of understanding. Voting to close.

Comment: It seems like the integers in one of your columns are so large that they are encoded as floats. E.g first entry in column "Value" is `6.28123E+11`. R can store integers as large as 2^31-1, 6.28123E+11 is more than a 100 times as large.

Comment: To second AkselA, from looking at your 94MB (!) large CSV file, the `Value` column has already been _exported_ in scientific format. If you need the full precision, you can try to _export_ as character and use the built-in  `integer64` support of `data.table::fread()`. Apropos 94 MB data file, please read [mcve].